# Pourquoi « cet s » ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, démonstratifs

> Dans la langue écrite le pluriel se forme, dans la plupart des noms,
>   en ajoutant un s à la forme du singulier. Mais **cet s** ne se
>   prononce pas.

J'ai rencontré ce passage dans un livre. Pourquoi **cet s** et pas **ce s** ? Est-ce une faute de frappe ?

Comment: Parce que _esse_, la forme prononcée de la lettre s, commence par une voyelle.

Comment: bien sûr, *ce s* est aussi possible.

Comment: @jlliagre Non seulement possible, mais bien plus courant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selon "[Le nom et le genre des lettres - l'h, le h, un h, une h, un ache - l's, le s, une esse - etc.](http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-le-nom-des-lettres-une-h-un-h-l-h-le-h-112484780.html)" (LE BLOG DE MAMIEHIOU):

> On a coutume aujourd'hui de donner le genre masculin au nom des lettres. Un A, un B, un L, un X, etc. Il n'en a pas toujours été ainsi. Certaines lettres, dont le nom commence par une voyelle, étaient des substantifs féminins.
>
> On peut dire encore le féminin pour F, L, M, N, R, S, H (prononcer une effe, une elle, une emme, une enne, une erre, une esse, une ache) mais cet usage tombe en désuétude.
>
> **On peut faire ou ne pas faire d'élision, l'h ou le h, l's ou le s.**
>   On trouve, dans la littérature, une I, une H muette ou aspirée, une L mouillée, un I grec, une X (rare) etc. Cf. *Grevisse*

Selon le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s):

> Prononc. et Orth.: [εs]. Élision: *l's, d's,* ou **liaison**, *trois s, un s, son s, plié en s.* Dans *les s,* la non liaison est la plus probable. Dans les abrév. et sigles: *la S.D.N.*, mais *l'S.O.S* ds Peyré, *Matterhorn,* 1939, p. 226.

Comment: Dans ***cet** s*, *s* est masculin (un esse). On ne rencontre plus vraiment ***cette** s*.

Comment: @jlliagre: Oui, "cet s" est masculin. Mais je pense qu'il était possible d'écrire "cette s" dans le passé, comme dans ce livre: https://books.google.com/books?id=KIY-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA87

Comment: Tout cela est vrai, mais, si c'est bien ce que signifie ta réponse, dire que l'on peut écrire *cet s* parce que *s* était il y a longtemps féminin est discutable.

Comment: Cette question n'a rien a voir avec le genre. Savoir que *s* a pu être féminin dans le passé n'explique absolument rien. L'absence de liaison peut par contre devenir une explication car le choix entre *ce* et *cet* intervient dans les même cas que les liaisons.